# How can I make PHPMyAdmin accessible to all domains?

Tags: centos, nginx

I've recently installed phpmyadmin and nginx on my server, but I want to make it accessible to all domains without copying it to every single domain's web root. Is this possible? if so, how?

**EDIT:** This is what's in my config now, lain

```
        location /phpmyadmin/
        {
                alias /home/phpmyadmin/;
        }

        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$
        {
                alias /home/phpmyadmin/$1;
                include fcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location), location cannot be used inside `http` block. This means that you have to add locations for every virtualhost. However you can save your bunch of layouts into a separate file and include it with `include`command. Here is an example for a generic virtualhost:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/nginx-default;

  include /etc/nginx/global.d/*.conf;
}
```

And you write all *global* locations in a separate `*.conf` files under `/etc/nginx/global.d`. Your code may be placed in `/etc/nginx/global.d/phpmyadmin.conf`, for example.

**Update:** As for your PHPMyAdmin locations: instead of aliasing every file you should pass SCRIPT_FILENAME variable in the following way:

```
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    include fcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Note that you need to use `/home/phpmyadmin` instead of `$document_root` because alias directive does not change document root. This means that for my generic virtualhost (as above) requesting URL `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/test.php` will try to execute `/var/www/nginx-default/phpmyadmin/test.php` which is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: That's rather genius. Thanks. However, why is my location not working? Do you know?

Comment: thanks for the update. Still getting 404 though, and `/home/phpmyadmin/` IS where the files are.

Comment: In most cases 404 error is issued by nginx. If this is the nginx 404 page and not fastcgi 404 error (blank screen for php-cgi/php-fpm, for example) then your php files don't match fastcgi location. Please check your nginx `error.log` for more information which one location takes precedence over your `/phpmyadmin/.+\.php` location.

Comment: What if it's the fastcgi?

Comment: You'll get an empty screen on default PHP-cgi/fastcgi setup. You'll get some meaningfull HTML results only if debug/error reporting flags are enabled in correspondent `php.ini`. In other cases you should look for a cgi/fastcgi-wrapper logs.

Comment: Also forgot to ask you to check file permissions: it is possible that cgi-wrapper cannot access your files due to permission issues.

Comment: Doesn't look like permission issues, but it's definitely the fastcgi 404.

Answer (score 1):

Put your phpmyadmin in a common directory that is accessible by all sites and try an [Alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)

```
location  /phpmyadmin/ {
  alias  /path/to/phpmyadmin/;
}

location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
  alias /path/to/phpmyadmin/$1;
  include /path/to/your/fastcgi.config;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
}
```

If you don't use the unix socket fastcgi then the last line would probably be something like this

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Comment: Will I need to put that line in every server {}, or is there a way to make it global?

Comment: I think so, there isn't any way to make a global loation.

Comment: After a bit of research, I've found the answer is no. As such, I've put that line in a few of the server blocks for a few domains; it isn't working :( It returns 404

Comment: Did you put the trailing `/` on the URL in your browser ? Without it as written above it will 404. f you remove the trailing / from the location block you don't need it in your URL.

Comment: Well this is strange. It seems it simply can't find the .php files... .html and .txt files are working fine.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @lain thanks, but still getting 404.

Comment: @lain added exactly what i added to my config. strangely enough, going to any standard php file (not in that location) works fine, and i'm using the same fcgi.conf for those that i'm using for the phpmyadmin

Comment: 404 is a different problem. If I remove the fcgi stuff I get the php delivered as text so you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: But I only get 404 for PHP files in that location. All other files are fine.

Comment: Is there no way I can track the file it's trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

@Rob you can change your log level to debug to follow nginx operations. You have to fix your SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter from fcgi.conf file or you can set it in your conf file.

Comment: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
` What do you mean fix? What's wrong with it?

Comment: if you change log level to debug, you can find problem. It will show you which files are tried to open or you can use strace easily to follow nginx process.